# React Native - cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

Since my app is fetching images from API and rendering the result as expected. But showing this warning is incomplete to this project and given answers aren't solved out my issue.

Moreover, it couldn't be solved with AbortController to pass the signal as a parameter in fetch call and using `AbortController.abort()` in `componentWillUnmount`

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount 
method.
```

CODE:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getImage(Flikr_URL);
  }

  getImage(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson =>
        this.setState({
          imageData: responseJson.photos.photo,
          loading: false
        })
      )
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw error;
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.getImage();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple solution, this will help you. May be another good solution will be there, but for now you can do like this.

Check manually component is mounted or not.
then in componentDidMount method set flag componentMounted to true.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.componentMounted = true;
    this.getImage(Flikr_URL);
  }
  getImage(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (this.componentMounted) { // check here component is mounted
          this.setState({
            imageData: responseJson.photos.photo,
            loading: false
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw error;
      });
  }
```

In componentWillUnmount method set flag to false

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.componentMounted = false;
  }
```

Comment: Then you can also use abort controller to stop fetch request - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Comment: I have tried it before I post this question but no luck. The warning is still displaying